# adding a certificate to Oracle Wallet

Tags: oracle-wallet

Are wallets dedicated to the pc where we have created them? or can I move my ewallet.p12 file to another client?

If the answer is "yes, why not?" then could you take a look below?

I did:

- create mijn_wallet on a pc on which I could find a proper oracle client installation
- download the certificate to a folder
- add certificate to mijn_wallet

then I tried to reach to https web site that I've gotten the certificate from.

```
...
utl_http.set_wallet('file:C:\ora_wall', 'foo');
l_req  := utl_http.begin_request(l_url);
l_result := utl_http.get_response(l_req);
```

however, I keep getting the same sql error message: Certificate Validation Failure

[image]

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downloading "a certificate" is not enough. moments ago I downloaded all the certificate chain, then imported to my wallet. Now it works..